# Including y-errors when bootstrapping - python package seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I am calculating bootstrap confidence intervals using the seaborn package for bootstrapping (https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html). I am looking to include y-errors in the calculation, however, I am not seeing a clear designation for this in the documentation. I initially thought that it might be x_estimator, but that only takes functions, such as np.mean, and not arrays, like y_err below. An example of my data set is below, and it can be seen that including the errors is important to the bootstrapping.

```
    import seaborn as sns
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    ax = sns.set(style="white", color_codes=True)
    ax=plt.figure(figsize=(18, 16), dpi= 80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
    y_err = [0.215,0.38,0.23,0.965,0.235,4.41,1.43,1.27,0.145,0.415]
    x, y = pd.Series([2.83,2.56,3.49,2.99,5.98,1.77,8.24,1.02,1.89,2.61215415], name="x data"), pd.Series([1.26,1.56,1.48,1.2,1.9,4.57,2.48,1.83,1.13,0.67], name='y data')
    ax = sns.regplot(x=x, y=y, ci=68,n_boot=1000,color='black')
    ax = sns.regplot(x=x, y=y, ci=95,n_boot=1000,color='red')
    ax = sns.regplot(x=x, y=y, ci=99.7,n_boot=1000,color='blue')
    ax = bar(x,y,yerr=y_err, facecolor='none')
    ax = plt.show()
```

Am I missing something obvious or is there a workaround for this?

Comment: To the small extent that I understand bootstrapping, the only correct way to apply bootstrapping would be to the full raw data set. If you have `y_err`s it implies you have already summarized your raw data. You shouldn't be applying bootstrapping to summarized data.

Comment: If you don't have the actual raw data, I suppose you could generate pseudo-raw data based on normally distributed random variates with mean `y` and std deviation `y_err`, but I'm not sure if such an approach has any theoretical validity.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. However, there are numerous scientific publications that utilize bootstrapping with y_err, so it's a common practice.